# Calculate uncertainty of a measurment given several measurments and uncertainties

Tags: error-analysis, statistics

I have several simulations of the same quantity (such as displacement $x$ after a simulated annealing run).
Then I average the quantity over $N$ runs of the simulations and calculate the mean $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i$ and the uncertainty $\Delta x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N(N-1)}\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\bar{x})^2}$.

Then, since I do not have enough disk space to save all the individual $x_i$, I can only save $\bar{x}\pm \Delta x$. Now I do the same procedure again and have a second measurment for $x$. Therefore, the values that I have are $\bar{x}^1\pm \Delta x^1$ and $\bar{x}^2\pm \Delta x^2$, the superscript being the index of the measurment.

How do I calculate the final average $\bar{x}$ and $\Delta x$ if I have several such measurments?

Comment: The way you define your uncertainty it would be come out to be zero. I think you are missing a square here.

Comment: Oh, yes sure! I also forgot that I have to divide the standard deviation by 1/sqrt(N) if I want to have the uncertainty of the mean value....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's denote a data set $x_{k,i}$ where $i$ is the index within a series and $k$ the index of series. The number of samples per series would $N_k$. Each series produces it's own mean, $\bar{x}_k$ and variance $\hat{x}_k$

The mean is easy 
$$\bar{x} = \frac{ \sum{\bar{x}_k \cdot N_k} }{ \sum{ N_k}}$$

The variance can be broken down as 
$$\hat{x}_k = \frac{1}{N_k-1} \dot(\sum_{i=0}^{N_k-1}x_{k,i}^2-2\cdot \bar{x}_k\sum_{i=0}^{N_k-1}x_{k,i}+N_k \cdot \bar{x}_k^2 )$$

$$\hat{x}_k = \frac{1}{N_k-1} \dot(\sum_{i=0}^{N_k-1}x_{k,i}^2-N_k \cdot \bar{x}_k^2 )$$

If you keep around the sum of squares and the the sum of the individual sample of each series, you can extend the equation to sums to multiple series.

Comment: Yeah, kind of, actually it can also be simplified, since the second term you wrote for the variance is equal -2 times the third term.
Or else: var(x) = E[x^2] - E[x]^2 where E is the expected value. Then I can square it and divide by 1/sqrt(N) to get my uncertainty of the mean value. 
So the only thing I need to save is E[x], E[x^2] and the amount of samples N i had.
And in the end I don't only get a variance and uncertainty for each individual simulation series but one for the total.

Comment: good point. I added the simplification